# remove username field from the CreateUserWizard asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, customization, createuserwizard

I am developing a site where Email address should be used as the login name. Hence I am looking for options to remove the 'Username' field from the CreateUserWizard and keep only Email ID, Password,Confirm Password in the page. when I just removed the Username text box from the ASP.Net Page, it threw the exception.
CreateUserWizardStep.ContentTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username.
Any ideas how to remove the Username Textbox from the createuserwizard?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is, 
Remove the `email` field from the wizard and modify the `username` label to `email`. Put validator to validate the username as an email. So Email should be validate when you click the create user button. Finally the bottom line is your user name is your email and vice versa.

See this  [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1841373.aspx/1/10)